# Grounding GPIO with separate PS to relay (not relay board)?

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to control a 12 VDC Bosch Automotive relay with an RPi. I am using a separate 12 VDC power supply to trigger the relay. The RPi is using GPIO18 which is connected to a 1k resistor, which is connected to the base of a 2N2222 transistor whose collector is connected to the relay output and emitter connected to the 12 VDC power supply negative lead.

I am not sure if the correct grounding of the RPI would be past the transistor to the 12 VDC PS? See line with "?" in below diagram. I have read in multiple posts that RPi GPIO does not need grounding, and then have been told it could not work without grounding (but mine actually does). I would love clarification and correction of my schematic if I have it wrong.

[image]

Comment: cut the connection that is short circuiting the collector and the emitter ... then it looks ok

Comment: It totally depends if the grounds are alreay connected via another route. You tell absolutely nothing about the RPi suppy or the 12 supply.

Comment: You can use optocoupler if you do not want to connect grounds.

Comment: jsotola - could you kindly indicate which connection is shorting collector to emitter? I am not understanding which it is. If I am shorting, it would be of great help to know where. TY

Comment: There is a straight line from the negative pole of the 12 volt power supply to where it turns 90° up to go to the relay. The transistor's emitter and collector are both connected to it. Between the emitter and collector the line should be erased.

Comment: user263983 - TY for that response, I will research optocopler as a means to protect RPi ground to 12VDC PS ground.

Comment: An optocoupler primary is almost always an LED. So from the Pi's perspective, you would treat it like an LED. Presuming it's a simple phototransistor on the secondary side (optocouplers vary widely), you would hook it up the way you have shown the BJT above (except for connecting the emitter and collector together). In that case, there is no need (indeed, it's counterproductive) to connect the emitter to the ground on the primary. It's the light from the LED that turns on the secondary rather than current flow.

Comment: nsayer - TY tons - I do not have that connection ion my board, but the line certainly should be erased from the schematic. My mistake for sure

Comment: If you add a optocoupler between the RPI and the 2n2222, you can avoid issues with a common ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that collector current (from collector to emitter) is allowed to flow by a BJT transistor in response to a current from the base to the emitter. In order for the base current to flow, there must be a common ground between the Pi and the emitter. So, yes, you must make that connection if there isn't already a common ground in place.

Comment: TY nsayer!! I needed that confirmation - was afraid to blow the RPi with that 12VDC ground connection

Comment: It's conceivable that you could have problems making that ground connection - if both power supplies are not isolated and don't have a common ground, then you could wind up with current flowing between the two grounds, which would be bad. However, most modern DC power "wall wart" supplies are isolated, so tying grounds together is ok.

Comment: so, would you also suggest an isocoupler as  user263983 suggested? Between RPi ground and common PS common ground?

Comment: If you're powering the pi and the relay from isolated supplies, then I would not bother. Optocouplers are useful in situations where either safety or noise immunity demands galvanic isolation, and I don't think either is the case here.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You should give consideration to the potential for coil collapse blowback to damage the transistor. The textbook way of solving this is to place a small diode across the relay coil, cathode to positive. Another method is a zener diode (voltage > 12V, but < Vcemax) across the transistor. But when the transistor opens, all of the energy stored in the relay coil is going to induce a large voltage on the transistor collector, and if that exceeds the abs max Vce, the transistor may be destroyed.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! TY VM

Comment: Yup, I do have a diode across coil. I know this is going to be a silly question, but a resistor on the collector side would be silly, as it would reduce the 12VDC stream, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can work out what the resistor would do with Ohm's law: E=IR. The voltage drop across the resistor (E) is equal to the resistance times the current through the resistor. You would (again, theoretically) also need to calculate the power through the resistor P=E^2/R or P=I^2*R to make sure you pick a beefy enough one.

Comment: Tons appreciated - will do! TY for all your help